# jQuery interfering with header (location)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

On my index I have a jQuery script to load files into my wrapper div. But if I load `submit2.php` into the div and in the file it has header (location) in it, it redirects the page into the div. However I want the whole page to redirect as in `_self` for `<a>` links.

Any way around this or something I've done wrong for it to interfere?

jQuery script for loading files into div:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var trigger = $('#nav ul li a'), container = $('#wrapper');
    trigger.on('click', function() {
      var $this = $(this), target = $this.data('target');
      container.load(target + '.php');
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

submit2.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include('config.php');
  $con = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
  $error = "";
  if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['pass'])) {
    $error = "Both fields are required.";
  } else {
    $loginpass = md5($_POST['pass']);
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$user'";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $checkuser=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($checkuser!=1) {
      $error = "username doesn't exist in our database!";
    }
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $checkpass = $row['password'];
      $user_id = $row['id'];
      $level = $row['usergroup'];
      if ($loginpass == $checkpass) {
        $_SESSION['login_user'] = $user;
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
        $_SESSION['start'] = time();
        $_SESSION['user_level'] = $level;
        echo ("succesfully logging in");
        header("Location: panel/index.php");
    } else {
        $error = "Incorrect Password!";
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It will not solve your problem, but don't echo anything before send headers, or it'll not work.

Comment: Try to use $.ajax and use the returned values from your PHP script to control the behaviour of your page instead the other way around.

Comment: @Mario_Lopez ahhh I see what your saying as i can use window.location.href right? Is there much difference between window.location.href and header(location:)?