# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function loginRelocate() Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Receiving error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function loginRelocate()

loginRelocate() is javascript function to redirect page if user is logged in.

Rest of code works.

login.php

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<?php include('submit2.php');
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
   loginRelocate();
}
?>
<div id="content" class="content">
   <div class="content-heading">
      <div class="content-heading-title">
      <h3>Login</h3>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="content-info">
   <form id="myForm" method="post">
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input name="username" id="username" type="text" /><br />
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input name="password" id="password" type="password" /><br /> 
      <input type="button" id="submitFormData" onclick="SubmitFormData();" value="Submit" />
   </form>
   <div id="results"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<script>
   function SubmitFormData() {
      var username = $("#username").val();
      var pass = $("#password").val();
      $.post("submit2.php", { 
         username: username, 
         pass: pass
      }, function(data) {
         $('#results').html(data);
         $('#myForm').trigger('reset');
      });
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function loginRelocate(){
      window.location.replace("panel/index.php");
   });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks

Comment: loginRelocate is a javascript function or a php function? I think that you are trying to calling a javascript function inside a php scope.

Comment: @RafaelSoufraz its a javascript function even if i move the js function within head tag same error

Comment: Try to copy and paste the code below an test in your system buddy. How can a javascript error throw a php exception?

Comment: In submit2.php do you have a function called loginRelocate?

Comment: @RafaelSoufraz snap yes i do i did same thing so sorry i forgot to mention  that forgot i did that i removed and still does nothing tho

Comment: Remove `)` after function defintion.

Comment: @u_mulder thanks yes sorry i didnt see that that solved the script working the other guys helped with me doing js in php so thanks and thanks to others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you cannot call a JavaScript function from PHP in that way... the correct way to do it is

```
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">loginRelocate();</script>';
}
```

or even

```
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
   ?> <script type="text/javascript">loginRelocate();</script> <?php
}
```

An alternative approach would be to use PHP to redirect the user and dispense with the JavaScript entirely:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
   header('Location: panel/index.php');
}
```

Or as a last ditch effort, use an HTML redirect:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
   ?> <meta http-equiv="location" content="URL=panel/index.php" /> <?php
}
```

This is discouraged, however.

Comment: He said that this doesn't work for him. I don't know what I can think anymore.

Comment: @Bjonnfesk thanks for your reply and the last approach i cant because i have this issue which i had to go around with javascript on this [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35457448/jquery-interfering-with-header-location jquery was interfeering with my header(location) and thanks for your replys i will try them :)

Comment: He did say that, but the comment in which he says it was posted while I was writing my post, hence I did not see it. I elected to leave it, however, because it may help others with similar problems.

Comment: @RafaelSoufraz and **Bjonnfesk** thanks the error went away but the script failed to do anything, any obvious things i did wrong in it?

Comment: i correct myself @RafaelSoufraz i left the ) at the end of my js that U_mudder spotted works thanks for showing me how to use the js in php ... i'm a student so much appreciated!

Comment: It is possible that you are still calling the function before it is declared... put the PHP part below the declaration of the JavaScript function instead (or declare the JavaScript above the PHP part), and see if it works. I know you tried this previously, but at that time you were still trying to call the JS function in an incorrect fashion. I also have one more last-ditch method you can try which I will edit in now.

Comment: @Bjonnfesk i left the ")" after } at the end of the function stopping it working ... it works perfect now no error and the js works in php :) thanks alot sir

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
loginRelocate is a javascript function or a php function? I think that you are trying to calling a javascript function inside a php scope.

```
<?php include('submit2.php'); ?>
<html>
<head>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="content" class="content">
   <div class="content-heading">
      <div class="content-heading-title">
      <h3>Login</h3>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="content-info">
   <form id="myForm" method="post">
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input name="username" id="username" type="text" /><br />
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input name="password" id="password" type="password" /><br /> 
      <input type="button" id="submitFormData" onclick="SubmitFormData();" value="Submit" />
   </form>
   <div id="results"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<script>
   function SubmitFormData() {
      var username = $("#username").val();
      var pass = $("#password").val();
      $.post("submit2.php", { 
         username: username, 
         pass: pass
      }, function(data) {
         $('#results').html(data);
         $('#myForm').trigger('reset');
      });
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function loginRelocate(){
      window.location.replace("panel/index.php");
   });
</script>

<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
   echo "<script>loginRelocate();</script>";
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: didn't work same error just different location the reason i had to use JS is because php header(location: ) wouldn't work it was conflicting with my jquery [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35457448/jquery-interfering-with-header-location[/link] as on that link ... but yano no-one could help with that issue so i tried to go around it with javascript

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `loginRelocate` before you declare it.
Try moving your declaration to the top of your page.

```
<head>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loginRelocate(){
        window.location.replace("panel/index.php");
   });
</script>   
</head>
```

Comment: You cannot call a PHP function from JavaScript in that way.

Comment: You cannot call a PHP function from JavaScript in that way.  ²